# Super sensitive slide on mobile using fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, slide, fullpage.js

Im building a site using this great plugin.

I currently have 2 problems.

1. I have 3 slides, all of them have different contents and therefore sizes on mobile. First slide is much higher than the other 2. When viewing in mobile the first slide overflow is hidden after 100vh. I want to be able to scroll down on that slide without the others being affected.
2. The second problem is that these slides are super sensitive to touch gestures. Every time I scroll down to that section, I move to the second slide, and every time I touch the screen again, I move to the next or previous slide randomly, all the time.

I tried touchSensitivity with no luck.

https://pages.devex.com/power-with-purpose-dev.html#christiana-figueres

Comment: I don't like to force things with `!important` but doing: `div#section2 { height: auto!important; }` let's you see the first slide as expected (i think). Which slider are you using? maybe it has an option that let's the slider adjust to it's content.

Comment: @CarlosMateo yep, using `fp-auto-height` does it. Check [this topic regarding responsive auto-height](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1852). My recommendation is to avoid using scrollOverflow. Make the site real responsible instead by removing the unnecessary or getting rid of autoScrolling to have bigger sections when necessary. Content over design.